# Cant flash any new firmware - Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet with CWM

Tags: external-sd, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery

I have problem with my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet. One day it just stopped working and get stuck on Lenovo logo on start. I tried to use recovery mod (pushing VOL UP several times during start), it says that it cant mount /cache directory. I tried Wipe cache and Factory reset options, non worked, still same problem. So I googled and found, that I am not the only one with this problem. I found and read this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2318140 and then this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1745450 and flashed CWM on partition 6, so now I have CWM-based Recovery (v6.0.1.2). I downloaded CyanogenMod (CM10 Alpha 0.8.1), copied to my SD Card (formated as FAT32) and tried Install zip from sdcard -> Choose zip from external sdcard. But I get E: Cant mount /extern_sd/ and I am stuck.

Tried to google this, but I found only alternative recovery mod (TWRP), but it cant be used for my device (at least I think so, since Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet is not listed in supported devices list).

Can you give me any pointers what to do next? I am kinda lost now